# Fitting power/exponential curve that goes through a specific point

Tags: python, r, regression, curve-fitting

I would like to fit an exponential or asymptotic model:

[image]

or

[image]

What matters is that the model should be concave and display some kind of saturation effect.

We have 2 exogenous variable x1, x2 and one constraints: the fitted curve should go trough the origin and another point.

If I fit my function, I can get this, which is pretty good for one variable.

`n1 <- nls(y ~ A*x1^(B), start=list(A=80, B = 0.5), data = a)`

[image]

Now I would like to add a second variable x2 that would only affect the curvature, and essentially would go through the same extreme top right point.

I tried couple of things like add x2 as a product with parameter b but it turns out that totally change the level of the curve, which I do not want.

Here is an example of the output I would be able to model for 5 different values of x2

[image]

I am confortable with python and scipy curve_fit so if you feel more comfortable sharing insight with python I am happy with that.

EDIT:

x2 is another variable observed along with x1. I would like to use x2 as well to explain y. As an example, let say there is a linear relationship between x2 and y.

[image]

Now, I would like that independent variable x2, being able to influence the curvature. The context tells me that the variable x2 can not move the level of the curve, and whatever the value of x2, y should always go through top most point, however, x2 does affect the curvature.

How can I model this?

I know as you said that I need to expand the functional form to be able to express the impact of x2 on the curvature only, but can't figure that out.

Comment: Can you please edit your post to indicate that you cross-posted it at [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/503804/1352)?

Answer (score 0):

This is really a math question rather than a programming question.  Let's take the saturating exponential (which has three parameters, so constraining two of them to force the curve through (0,0) and the rightmost point (which I'll call (`xr`,`yr`)) will leave one free parameter. Given that `f(x) = a-(a-b)*exp(-c*x)`

- If we want `f(0)=0` we need to set `b=0` (math left as an exercise)
- What about `f(xr)=yr` ?

```
a*(1-exp(-c*xr)) = yr  ## set b=0
a = yr/(1-exp(-c*xr))  ## solve for a
```

Here's some example data:

```r
xvec <- 0:100
set.seed(101)
dd <- data.frame(x=xvec,y=rnorm(length(xvec),3*(1-exp(-0.03*xvec)),sd=0.2))
yr <- dd$y[length(xvec)]
xr <- dd$x[length(xvec)]
```

Here's a function that implements the algebra above:

```r
cfun <- function(x,c) {
    a <- yr/(1-exp(-c*xr))
    return(a*(1-exp(-c*x)))
}
```

```r
plot(y~x,data=dd)
points(c(0,xr),c(0,yr),pch=16,col=2)
curve(cfun(x,0.01),add=TRUE)
curve(cfun(x,0.04),add=TRUE)
curve(cfun(x,.1),add=TRUE)
```

[image]

In this case I chose to use the rightmost point which happened not to be the topmost point, but you can pick whatever values you want for `xr`, `yr` ...

---

If you wanted to make the curvature depend on another variable (such as `x2`) you could make `c` a linear function of that variable, something like

```
nls(y~ cfun(x1, c=d+e*x2), data=..., start=list(d=0.03, e=0))
```

---

For the power-law form (which already satisfies the (0,0) constraint), solve for `a` in terms of `xr`, `yr`, and `b`, and proceed as above ...

```
a*xr^b = yr
a = yr/(xr^b)
```

Comment: That definitely helps a lot regarding the "go through a point" constraint. However, how can I add to that constraint the initial curve fitting problem? I managed to fit a curve with one variable, what if I want to add a second variable x2, and fit the curve that follows the same constraint about the topmost point?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand.  Is `x2` a predictor variable (i.e. something that you've observed along with `x1` for every data point) or a parameter?  Can you edit your question to give an example?  I've shown the curves for three different values of `c` (perhaps corresponding to your `x2`? It mostly affects the curvature) ... do you want to expand the functional form with an additional parameter?   Why? Can you say more about the context? (This is definitely heading into [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com) territory ...

Comment: I have done an edit. x2 is another predictor variable that can only affect the curvature. The data where the system come from can only affect the curvature and not the level of the curve.